# What's a good way to replace international characters with their base Latin counterparts using Python?

Tags: python, string, internationalization

Say I have the string `"blöt träbåt"` which has a few `a` and `o` with umlaut and ring above. I want it to become `"blot trabat"` as simply as possibly. I've done some digging and found the following method:

```
import unicodedata
unicode_string = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', unicode(string))
```

This will give me the string in unicode format with the international characters split into base letter and combining character (`\u0308` for umlauts.) Now to get this back to an ASCII string I could do `ascii_string = unicode_string.encode('ASCII', 'ignore')` and it'll just ignore the combining characters, resulting in the string `"blot trabat"`.

The question here is: is there a better way to do this? It feels like a roundabout way, and I was thinking there might be something I don't know about. I could of course wrap it up in a helper function, but I'd rather check if this doesn't exist in Python already.

Comment: "The ASCII string "blöt träbåt"" is a contradiction. ASCII doesn't have accented characters. Did you mean "The Unicode string"?

Comment: Hey, that's exactly the same thing I'm doing in C#...

Comment: Yeah I just realized I used the wrong term. It doesn't necessarily have to be Unicode, though. It can be extended ASCII (which was what I really meant.)

Comment: @orsogufo: When I was making this question, the top suggestion was a solution for C#, so search for that `=)`

Comment: @Blixt: thanks, I meant I've already implemented it like that :) seems to be a standard way. Just out of curiosity: why do you need to do it?

Comment: I'm making a command interpreter for a text-based game that needs to be pretty lax, so one of the ways I go about that is to keep the characters used to the ASCII set of characters. So `café` becomes `cafe`, etc.

Comment: It would probably be easier just to support ASCII, and throw an error when anything else is entered, saying something like "ERROR - Input not ascii!"

Comment: @Blixt: "extended ASCII" is a meaningless phrase. There are many ways of extending ASCII; they are collectively called "character sets". Any interesting character set is an extension of ASCII.

Comment: @Martin: Yes. I'll be falling back to ISO-8859-1 specifically, if the string supplied is not Unicode.

Comment: @monkut: Of course, but I'm looking for an as lean user experience as possible. If a user types `"go to café"` because that spelling comes naturally to them, I don't see any reason not to interpret their text as the command `"go to cafe"`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would be better if you created an explicit table, and then used the unicode.translate method. The advantage would be that transliteration is more precise, e.g. transliterating "ö" to "oe" and "ß" to "ss", as should be done in German.

There are several transliteration packages on PyPI: [translitcodec](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/translitcodec/0.1), [Unidecode](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode/0.04.1), and [trans](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/trans/1.0).

Comment: You're right, transliteration is better than just removing the decorations from characters. If `"große"` became `"grose"`, that would be confusing (not that I think I'll be dealing with German words, but still)...

Comment: I use *translitcodec* since it appears to be the most professionally structured module. It also, unlike *trans*, replaces `å` with `aa` and `ä` with `ae` as is proper when translitering.

Comment: @Blixt: sorry, I can't help with a recommendation of a specific package - this might be a separate SO question. However, it appears that you have done an evaluation already.