# Python regex to convert non-ascii characters in a string to closest ascii equivalents

Tags: python, regex, character-encoding, ascii, special-characters

I'm seeking simple Python function that takes a string and returns a similar one but with all non-ascii characters converted to their closest ascii equivalent.
For example, diacritics and whatnot should be dropped.
I'm imagining there must be a pretty canonical way to do this and there are plenty of related stackoverflow questions but I'm not finding a simple answer so it seemed worth a separate question.

Example input/output:

```
"Étienne" -> "Etienne"
```

Comment: How do you define "closest?"

Comment: Good question! I guess I'm hoping not to have to define it, that there's some standard, accepted mapping somewhere.  I'm sure this is hairier than I imagine to do really right, but partial solutions would be valuable as well.

Comment: `iconv` can do it with a `//TRANSLIT` flag, not sure whether there are any proper Python bindings for it though.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586903/sqlite-remove-non-utf-8-characters and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854230/whats-the-fastest-way-to-strip-and-replace-a-document-of-high-unicode-characters

Comment: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode/ related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-in-a-python-unicode-string http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192367/whats-a-good-way-to-replace-international-characters-with-their-base-latin-count http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854230/whats-the-fastest-way-to-strip-and-replace-a-document-of-high-unicode-characters http://stackoverflow.com/questions/816285/where-is-pythons-best-ascii-for-this-unicode-database

Answer (score 6):

Reading this question made me go looking for something better.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode/0.04.1

Does exactly what you ask for.

Comment: Just `pip install unidecode` and it works even with Chinese! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In Python 3 and using the regex implementation at PyPI:

```
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex
```

Starting with the string:

```
>>> s = "Étienne"
```

Normalise to NFKD and then remove the diacritics:

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> import regex
>>> regex.sub(r"\p{Mn}", "", unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", s))
'Etienne'
```

Comment: That really doesn’t do much. For example, code point U+00F8, *ø*, does **not** decompose to something with Marks. But it still has the same primary collation strength as *o* has: 138E per DUCET 6.0.  Similarly, there is no decomposition for code point U+00F0, *ð.* However, its primary collation strength is the same as a *d* at 1250. People need to learn to work *with* Unicode, not against it!

Comment: I’ve looked at the library you mention, and it looks very exciting. Are you its author? I’ve been interested in a Python library with better Unicode support for quite a while now. Let me look it over and send you mail. Thanks very much.

Comment: Can you explain the meaning of `r"\p{Mn}"`? I just read through the regex docs, and I don't understand what Mn signifies.

Comment: `\p{Mn}` will match a codepoint which has the `Mn` or (or `Nonspacing_Mark`) Unicode property. Other properties include `Lu` (`Uppercase_Letter`) and `Cyrillic`.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a search for 'iconv TRANSLIT python' I found:
http://www.tablix.org/~avian/blog/archives/2009/01/unicode_transliteration_in_python/ which looks like it might be what you need. The comments have some other ideas which use the standard library instead.

There's also http://web.archive.org/web/20070807224749/http://techxplorer.com/2006/07/18/converting-unicode-to-ascii-using-python/ which uses NFKD to get the base characters where possible.

Answer (score 1):

Read the answers to some of the duplicate questions. The NFKD gimmick works only as an accent stripper. It doesn't handle ligatures and lots of other Latin-based characters that can't be (or aren't) decomposed. For this a prepared translation table is necessary (and much faster).

Comment: Thanks John.  I really hate to see people mutilating Unicode data. Usually it's because they don't know how to do a comparison at collation strength 1 (primary) only. For example, at level 1 there are 99 A's, 43 B's, 53 C's, etc.  O has the most at 111, Q the fewest at 34.  NFKD ups those numbers a bit, pusing A's to 115 and O's to 119 for example.