# python: Replacing special characters in a string

Tags: python, special-characters

I read the artist of a song from its MP3 tag, then create a folder based on that name.  The problem I have is when the name contains a special character like 'AC\DC'.  So I wrote this code to deal with that.

```
def replace_all(text):
  print "replace_all"
  dictionary = {'\\':"", '?':"", '/':"", '...':"", ':':"", chr(148):"o"}

  for i, j in dictionary.iteritems():
      text = text.replace(i,j)

  return text
```

What I am running into now is how to deal with non-english characters like an umlaout o in Motorhead or Blue Oyster cult.

As you see I tried adding the ascii-string version of umlaout o at the end of the dictionary but that failed with

```
UnicodeDecodeError:  'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833791/python-regex-to-convert-non-ascii-characters-in-a-string-to-closest-ascii-equival for discussion of a more general solution.

Comment: @Ignacio That is a great link!  It helped alot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this code, though I don't understand it.

```
def strip_accents(s):
  return ''.join((c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', s) if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn'))
```

It enabled me to remove the accent marks from the path of proposed dir/filenames.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using unicode for both input text and the chars replaced. In your example `chr(148)` is clearly not a unicode symbol.

Comment: So how do I take a string that has a unicode character inside of it and force the entire string to be set to unicode?  And does doing that then change to non-unicode chars of the string?

Comment: You probably have a simple string (byte/binary string) in a specific encoding, such as ISO-8859-1 or UTF-8. You need to decode from that encoding to Python's unicode data type, like this: `utext = text.decode('utf-8')`.